# Getting "pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed" error while using rabbitmq in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using "hello world" tutorial in :http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html .
`worker.py` looks like this

```
import pika
import time


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)
    time.sleep( body.count('.') )
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='task_queue')

channel.start_consuming()
```

I have used this code to implement in my work. Everything works smoothly untill there comes a point in a queue for which it raises an exception after printing `[x] Done`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hullworker2.py", line 242, in <module>
    channel.basic_consume(callback,queue='test_queue2')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/channel.py", line 211, in basic_consume
    {'consumer_tag': consumer_tag})])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 904, in _rpc
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 88, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 184, in _handle_read
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 300, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 264, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 181, in _handle_disconnect
    self._on_connection_closed(None, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 232, in _on_connection_closed
    self._channels[channel]._on_close(method_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 817, in _on_close
    self._send_method(spec.Channel.CloseOk(), None, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 920, in _send_method
    self.connection.send_method(self.channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 120, in send_method
    self._send_method(channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1331, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Method(channel_number, method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 245, in _send_frame
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._send_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1312, in _send_frame
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

I don't understand how the connection is closing automatically in between the process. Process runs fine for 100's of messages in the queue then suddenly this error comes up.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the stack trace error that you get? It should start with something like Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> .....

Comment: @kobejohn I have updated the ques please see it

Comment: I don't have rabbitmq setup so I'm just guessing. It seems strange that the traceback shows the error in basic_consume. There shouldn't be any callbacks running until after start_consuming() right? How long does this work before it crashes?

Comment: 30-40 minutes then it display the results and crashes.Again if i start the worker it will take the same message

Comment: This error is not coming from worker.py is it? Maybe you are looking in the wrong place for the source of the problem? Can you give a simplified version of hullworker2.py? Also, if you can just catch the ConnectionClosed exception and restart the worker, do you lose work? I guess you will be fine because you are using acknowledgement which doesn't complete a job until it is acknowledged. If that's ok, then you can just restart when necessary as a temporary fix.

Comment: yes I didnt lose the work but it is stuck at the same message.When I restart it receive the same message execute the "calculations" and then shows the same error.And in the calculation I used print statements to check if its calculating or not.Its giving the results perfectly but can not acknowledge it for some reasons I guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a concept of `heartbeats`. It's basically  a way how the server can make sure that the client is still connected.

when you do

```
time.sleep( body.count('.') )
```

You blocking the code by `N` number of seconds. It means that if server would like to send a `heartbeat` frame to check if your client is still alive, then it will not get a response back, because your code is blocked and doesn't know if heartbeat arrived.

Instead of using `time.sleep()` you should use `connection.sleep()` this will also make the code "sleep" for `N` number of seconds, but it will also communicate with the server and will respond back.

```
 sleep(duration)[source]

    A safer way to sleep than calling time.sleep() directly which will keep the adapter from ignoring frames sent from RabbitMQ. The connection will “sleep” or block the number of seconds specified in duration in small intervals.
```

Comment: while this answer solves the issue in the question. I think it does not resolved the problem of long task and the hearbeats properly.