# Getting “pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed” error while using rabbitmq in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to use rabbitmq in python.
My code is:

```
import pika

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
```

I am running this file using:

```
python3 test.py
```

Error Signature:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061082/getting-pika-exceptions-connectionclosed-error-while-using-rabbitmq-in-python) , but i dont have any sleep in my code.
Not really sure what could go wrong.
Please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with rabbitmqctl. Reconfigured it, Restarted service, and the issue is fixed.

1. Make sure rabbitmqctl is installed(if installed, uninstall it and re-install;when you just enter rabbitmqctl, it should display the help)
2. rabbitmqctl start_app

TIP: I tried installing first using 'brew',but for some reason, I was not able to get it right. So installed,    rabbitmqctl as a separate package and added to PATH

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? How to reconfigure `rabbitmqctl` exactly?